# Putting text at the bottom of the page

Tags: vertical-alignment

Have a look at the MWE example below. I want the text to appear at the bottom of the page rather than on top. I tried the \vfill option, but this does not seem to do the job. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\vfill
© Copyright by KU Leuven\\

Without written permission of the promotors and the authors it is forbidden 
to reproduce or adapt in any form or by any means any part of this  publication.   
Requests for obtaining the right to reproduce or utilize parts of this publication 
should be addressed to KU Leuven, Faculteit Wetenschappen, Geel Huis, 
Kasteelpark Arenberg 11 bus 2100, 3001 Leuven (Heverlee), Telephone +32 16 32 14 01.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\vspace*{\fill}` and remove the `\\ ` from the ends of paragraphs, they are always wrong and generate underfull box warnings.

Comment: Alternatively, you can place something before the \vfill, like \null or \strut.

Answer (score 76):

**The following worked for me:** 
*(note: I'm simply reposting a comment above as an answer)*

```
Some random text in the page
\vspace*{\fill}
Text that will now be at the bottom of the page
```

Answer (score 11):

Placing `\mbox{}` before `\vfill` will do the job!

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\vfill
© Copyright by KU Leuven\\

Without written permission of the promotors and the authors it is forbidden 
to reproduce or adapt in any form or by any means any part of this  publication.   
Requests for obtaining the right to reproduce or utilize parts of this publication 
should be addressed to KU Leuven, Faculteit Wetenschappen, Geel Huis, 
Kasteelpark Arenberg 11 bus 2100, 3001 Leuven (Heverlee), Telephone +32 16 32 14 01.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!